# Move SQL Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I want to move my SQL Storage to another project without deleting or re-creating it. I have to do it without change IP, databases or users.

May Google allowing this ? I didn't see it anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: There's no way that I know of to do this. You'd need to export from the source DB and import into a new target DB. You'd also lose the public IP because you can't move it from project to project. Reliance on IP addresses in cloud is not the best practice.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod, i look everywhere except console but didn't find a solution :/